# Запись множества массивов в один .txt файл

Tags: python, массивы

Получаю информацию в виде массивов
При попытке записать это все в файл, записывается лишь один из массивов

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



url = 'https://www.proxyscan.io/'

def col(url):
   req = requests.get(url)
   soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
   result = soup.find_all('tr')
   for i in result:
      result = re.findall('\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}', i.text)
      
      for i in result:
         with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(result, file)


col(url)
```

Comment: Можно хотя бы код прикрепить?!

Comment: И как нам узнать в чем проблема? Приложите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: Приложил код к своему вопросу

Comment: Форматирование правильное? Переменные переиспользуются? Что такое regx, который каждый раз в файл пишется?

Comment: Форматирование правильно, переменная regx, это result тут когда скопировал не исправил секунду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in result:
         with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(regx, file)
```

Каждый раз, на каждой из иттераций цикла вы открываете один и тот-же файл `'file.txt'` а затем ПЕРЕЗАТИРАЕТЕ все, что в нем было до того, задав метод записи `'w'`. Измените `'w'`  на `'a'` и будет вам счастье.

P.S. По ходу даже не стал разбираться, зачем вы каждый раз открываете файл по-новой. Почему ельзя его открыть его один раз и писать туда все что вам  надо, а закрыть его в самом конце. Но вы об анализе кода не спрашивали -  поэтому даю наводку. А далее думайте сами.

P.P.S. Еще раз взглянул на код. Два вложенных цикла for, в каждом из них в качестве переменной цикла используется переменная i. Это жах. Может начать с чтения учебника все таки?

Comment: Хороший ответ :)

Comment: Помогло, благодарю!

Comment: @Lamer -  как новичку подсказываю https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers